# Broadcom problems. No driver in additional drivers

Tags: 11.04, wireless, broadcom

I had problem with broadcom drivers. The insternet was super-slow, 1kb/s was the max download speed. Then i was searching for a solution, and found a tip that offered to install bmcwl-kernel-source. I isnstalled it, restarted my computer, and there were no Wifi drivers. ( There were only Wired connection option ). I tried to use "Additional Drivers" but it won't show B43 anymore.

Help? :)

Ubuntu: 11.04

Kernel: 2.6.38-8 generic

Thanks :)

Comment: Maybe the following link could be of some help:
http://polach.cc/howto-fix-broadcom-wifi-adapter-wpa-network-access-on-ubuntu-10-04-lucid-lynx

Comment: edit your post to include the contents of `lspci | grep Broadcom`

Answer (score 1):

You should review the information on the official Ubuntu community help site.  [Click Here.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx)
The connection speed might not be related to the driver at all, but without more information, it's hard to tell.